Connecting two lines in ggplot2?
I am working with the  R programming language.
I have two datasets:

Historical_Data
Model_Predictions

Here is some R code which simulates the structure of the datasets I am using:
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

generate_historical_data <- function() {
    dates <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2009-12-01"), by = "month")
    values <- runif(length(dates), min = 100, max = 300)  
    data.frame(
        date = format(dates, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        value = round(values, 2),
        class = "Historical"
    )
}

generate_classified_data <- function(class, start_date, base_mean) {
    dates <- seq(start_date, by = "month", length.out = 120)
    
    t <- seq_len(length(dates))
    
    seasonal <- 20 * sin(2 * pi * t / 12)
    
    mean_values <- base_mean + seasonal + rnorm(length(dates), 0, 10)
    
    spread <- runif(length(dates), 15, 25)  # Consistent spread for confidence intervals
    
    data.frame(
        date = format(dates, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        mean_value = round(mean_values, 2),
        low_value = round(mean_values - spread, 2),
        high_value = round(mean_values + spread, 2),
        class = class
    )
}

historical_data <- generate_historical_data()

last_historical_date <- as.Date(max(historical_data$date))
prediction_start_date <- last_historical_date %m+% months(1)

model_predictions <- rbind(
    generate_classified_data("A", prediction_start_date, base_mean = 150),  
    generate_classified_data("B", prediction_start_date, base_mean = 300),  
    generate_classified_data("C", prediction_start_date, base_mean = 450)   
)

The two datasets look like this:
> head(historical_data)
        date  value      class
1 2000-01-01 923.33 Historical
2 2000-02-01 943.37 Historical
3 2000-03-01 357.53 Historical
4 2000-04-01 847.40 Historical
5 2000-05-01 677.57 Historical
6 2000-06-01 567.19 Historical

> head(model_predictions)
        date mean_value low_value high_value class
1 2010-01-01     156.33    135.73     176.93     A
2 2010-02-01     169.17    147.65     190.70     A
3 2010-03-01     175.82    158.02     193.61     A
4 2010-04-01     181.32    156.52     206.12     A
5 2010-05-01     152.73    131.29     174.17     A
6 2010-06-01     163.03    142.20     183.85     A

My Question: Using ggplot, I am trying to make a plot which plots the historical data, and then from the last point of historical data, plots the mean_value for the 3 classes (i.e. A, B, C) along with the low_value and high_value (i.e. to serve like a confidence interval).
I tried to do it like this:
ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = historical_data, 
              aes(x = date, y = value, color = class), 
              size = 1) +
    
    geom_line(data = model_predictions, 
              aes(x = date, y = mean_value, color = class), 
              size = 1) +
    
    geom_ribbon(data = model_predictions, 
                aes(x = date, 
                    ymin = low_value, 
                    ymax = high_value, 
                    fill = class), 
                alpha = 0.2) +
    
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Historical" = "black",
                                  "A" = "red",
                                  "B" = "blue",
                                  "C" = "green")) +
    
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "red",
                                 "B" = "blue",
                                 "C" = "green")) +
    
    labs(title = "Historical Data and Model Predictions",
         x = "Date",
         y = "Value",
         color = "Data Type",
         fill = "Prediction Class") +
    
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "right",
          plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12)) +
    
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", 
                 date_labels = "%Y") +
    
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 550))


Is it possible to make the 3 colored lines start exactly from where the black line ends?
Thanks!

I think I figured something out?
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

last_historical_point <- historical_data %>%
    arrange(date) %>%
    slice_tail(n = 1)

connection_points <- data.frame(
    date = rep(last_historical_point$date, 3),
    mean_value = rep(last_historical_point$value, 3),
    low_value = rep(last_historical_point$value, 3),
    high_value = rep(last_historical_point$value, 3),
    class = c("A", "B", "C")
)

# Combine with existing predictions
model_predictions_connected <- rbind(
    connection_points,
    model_predictions
)

historical_data$date <- as.Date(historical_data$date)
model_predictions_connected$date <- as.Date(model_predictions_connected$date)

# Create the plot
ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = historical_data, 
              aes(x = date, y = value, color = class), 
              size = 1) +
    
    geom_line(data = model_predictions_connected, 
              aes(x = date, y = mean_value, color = class), 
              size = 1) +
    
    geom_ribbon(data = model_predictions_connected, 
                aes(x = date, 
                    ymin = low_value, 
                    ymax = high_value, 
                    fill = class), 
                alpha = 0.2) +
    
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Historical" = "black",
                                  "A" = "red",
                                  "B" = "blue",
                                  "C" = "green")) +
    
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "red",
                                 "B" = "blue",
                                 "C" = "green")) +
    
    labs(title = "Historical Data and Model Predictions",
         x = "Date",
         y = "Value",
         color = "Data Type",
         fill = "Prediction Class") +
    
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "right",
          plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12)) +
    
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", 
                 date_labels = "%Y") +
    
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 550))



Do the black line plots not have any of the same years as the other 3 lines?

You can make a data frame with the last date and the last value in the historical data and include that data frame in your rbind.
last_historical_date <- as.Date(max(historical_data$date))
last_value <- historical_data[historical_data$date == last_historical_date, "value"]

StitchDF <- data.frame(date = rep(last_historical_date, 3),
                       mean_value = rep(last_value, 3),
                       low_value = c(NA,NA,NA),
                       high_value = c(NA,NA,NA),
                       class = c("A","B","C"))

prediction_start_date <- last_historical_date %m+% months(1)

model_predictions <- rbind(
  StitchDF,
  generate_classified_data("A", prediction_start_date, base_mean = 150),  
  generate_classified_data("B", prediction_start_date, base_mean = 300),  
  generate_classified_data("C", prediction_start_date, base_mean = 450))

Separately, your plot would be more legible if you converted all of the date columns to numeric dates with the ymd() function from lubridate.
